# Can bots hosted on Microsoft teams read their app manifest file?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Can a bot added to teams by sideloading it / from store access its own manifest file?
Any API;s for this? I would like to read the website url from the manifest file.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add "webURL" in config file and you can use the same url in your code. Is there any specific reason you want access weburl from manifest file?

Comment: I am not aware of the config file you mentioned. Could you please provide more details...

Comment: I want the end user requests to hit different backends, so wanted to use the url in manifest file to determine what the backend should be.

Comment: which file are you calling "app manifest file"? Which version of Bot Framework SDK would you like to use (which language)?

Comment: @user5734678 If you are using C#, web application, we can mention "weburl" in Web.config file and we can access same URL in your code as well.

Comment: We have build a bot using the bot framework rest API. We are then using the manifest file to sideload the bot into MS teams. No C# involved

Comment: End user request always hits the endpoint url which is configured in Bot Framework/Azure portal. Currently, there are no APIs available to fetch webUrl.

Comment: Is there a way to have a dynamic end point url ? Our app is multi region with each region having say a unique user. But giving each user a new bot is not a scalable solution for us. Any ideas what we could do?

Comment: There is no option to set end point Url dynamically. Also you won't be able to get location/region information in bot. You can try this:   
1. bot asks user to configure his location/region with bot 
2. Bot reply with answers based on configured region

Comment: Yes i am aware of that approach, but its bad for user experience. Is there no way to fetch the app manifest file of the bot using GET call ?

Answer (score 0):

The messaging endpoint for a bot isn't in the manifest anyway, so there is little value in being able to read the manifest.

Currently there is no way to have multiple (or dynamic) messaging endpoints for a bot. We will support this in the future, but currently the only way to do what you want is to have a central bot that acts as a proxy and forwards the request to a region-specific or tenant-specific instance. We have at least one partner who has implemented this approach and it does work.

We have a sample of such an approach called [Orky](https://github.com/OfficeDev/orky) which we've released as open source. It's not exactly what you are talking about because it's designed for end users to register the bots themselves and therefore the user has to use different commands to talk to each individual bot.

In your case that's not necessary - you would have one central Bot Framework bot and then tenant/regional instances that would connect to it over WebSockets, and the central bot would route messages automatically based on serviceUrl or tenantId - users would have no idea that there were really multiple instances. At any rate depending on your timeframe the Orky code could help you out; we likely will not support multiple endpoints per bot until late 2018 at the earliest.

Comment: We already had that approach in mind. But the question arises where would you host the bot? Say if its hosted in EU and someone from US messages, then latency would be an issue. Any solutions to that ?

Answer (score 0):

reading your question and the comments is like seeing a shadow of you, who went through the path that I want to go through. Now, it may be too late for you, but for future bot creators that require dynamic end point url to hit different backends, this solution i found may help them.

You can get the Body/PayLoad of your ChatBot in MS Teams when the user writes, in your AppService via Azure Bot Service:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task PostAsync([FromBody] object payload, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    string value = Convert.ToString(payload);
    ///blablabla...
}
```

Payload:

```
{
  "text": "helloWorld ",
  "textFormat": "plain",
  "attachments": [
    {
      "contentType": "text/html",
      "content": "<p>helloWorld </p>"
    }
  ],
  "type": "message",
  "timestamp": "2022-09-23T16:30:34.1849963Z",
  "localTimestamp": "2022-09-23T11:30:34.1849963-05:00",
  "id": "16639",
  "channelId": "msteams",
  "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/",
  "from": {
    "id": "29:1NHwlDI",
    "name": "Pepito Perez",
    "aadObjectId": "d25112"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationType": "personal",
    "tenantId": "638fcb",
    "id": "a:15F1YmnyJvEx"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "28:57a8ae07-50",
    "name": "mychatbotteamsxxx"
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "locale": "es-ES",
      "country": "ES",
      "platform": "Windows",
      "timezone": "America/Bogota",
      "type": "clientInfo"
    }
  ],
  "channelData": {
    "tenant": {
      "id": "638fcbaf-ba4c-43e"
    }
  },
  "locale": "es-ES",
  "localTimezone": "America/Bogota"
}
```

From this body/payload you can get the user who sends, then you must connect to a database that relates the user with the region/country/project/category, etc. bring what you need (endpoint, headers, payload), do all the logic you need, and connect to different backends through apis.